# XMPP framework - How to get Group messages

Tags: iphone, xmpp

Im developing an iPhone app that has an groupchat.

Im using the XMPP framework. But im not able to pick up the message that has been received and then pass it to the Viewcontroller in order to print it.

Im able to print one on one messages, but the way the framework deals with groupmessages is different.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989921/iphone-xmpp-chat-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you have to create a delegate that will call a method that is implemented in the viewcontroller.
In such way that the appDelegate(who is the only one to know that a message is received) will execute a method that is implemented in the viewcontroller. Then the viewcontroller will be able to print the received message.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you will receive a group message, following delegate method will be called:

```
(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message fromOccupant:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID
    {
      NSLog("Received Message : %@",[message body]);
    }
```

Comment: The question is totally different than the answer you have given. the above will receive messages when recipient send the message or receive offline messages once you are connected. The question is how to get group message.